# Is there a way to express C's '\a' and '\b' in Swift?

Tags: swift, escaping

Is there a way to express C's escape sequences `'\a'` and `'\b'` in Swift?
I know they are basic ascii values but I have no luck finding an equivalent. I have tried `"\u{7}" "\u{8}"` in Swift but when I print them I get no sound nor an alert. The truth is I have tried it printing onnly in Xcode so far, I am also going to try the terminal. Is there a way this would work in Swift that I am missing?

UPDATE:

I have tried in terminal but only the beep occurs. When I type "hi\u{8}" I expect the 'i' to be gone but it is not.

Comment: You just need to test your code with a terminal which is capable of playing beep.

Comment: I tried it in teminal and the beep works (y) but when i write "hi\u{8}" i expect the 'i' to be gone and it is not am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your expectation is highly depending upon the capability of the terminal you use. Find a terminal app which works as you describe. It is not the problem of language.

Comment: OK! Thanks, that is what I wanted to hear I did not exactly need to see it I just need to know that it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Backspace doesn't have to delete, it really just moves the cursor back one position. Try e.g. `"hi\u{8} "` (with a space after the backspace).

Comment: \a does not always beep: sometimes you need a ffflush(__stdoutp) before you hear the beep.